# What is the difference between using a database class, db absraction layer and orm?

Tags: php, database, orm

I've created a database class long time ago always used it in my projects.

Something like this:

```
class Database
{
     function query($sqlQuery) {
         $this->prepare($sqlQuery);
     }

     function connect($databaseConnectionValues) { }

     function read() { }

     function prepare() { }

     ...etc
}
```

Frameworks like Laravel do it in a completely different way. They never execute SQL.

Something like this:

```
$users->find('Demo')->select('email')->get();
```

I'll get two questions on this.

**Question 1:** I believe the second code is called as "ORM", but what is "Database Absraction Layer"? Also, how many layers do database has? (I can do further research when I get their names.)

**Question 2:** Why should I use an ORM and why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the skinny:

1. Database abstraction layer = a tool that takes database functions
   and syntax and re-packages them for use programatically.
2. ORM = Object Relational Mapper, which may include a database
   abstraction, goes one step further and allows you to manage
   relationships between tables via programmatic objects.

That would make this code snippet a database abstraction layer.

```
$users->find('Demo')->select('email')->get();
```

If it had some syntax like:

```
$users->join('Friends')->find('Demo')->select('email')->get();
```

Or similar you'd have an ORM on your hands.

The only time you would find an ORM useful is if you have to do join queries and want the results from more than one table pre-packaged nicely into their own models and then properly organized.  Example:

```
$u = $user->join('friends')->where('name', 'mike')->get();

echo $u->name; // would be mike;
echo $u->friends[0]->name; // would be the name of another user who's mike's friend
```

This is all very conceptual and framework agnostic of course.  In this case, a relationship would be defined in the model class that loads the "friends" property with all the users that are friends of the selected user.

If you are not doing joins on tables, don't worry about ORM functionality, even if your framework of choice has one.  You only need to use it if you need it.

Comment: Orm makes objects of your data and makes it easier to work with related objects.  Joins can also be done with a database abstraction  layer

Comment: @Miguelo, very true.  The difference would be that the abstraction layer wouldn't provide the same level of control over the data from the two or more tables.